# Recent orders are not appearing in the backend but exist in the database and are displayed in the dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.0.1, admin-panel, order-grid

```
I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0.
```

There are three recent orders that do not appear in the Sales > Orders panel. Here is a screenshot of the most recent orders, please see the order numbers:

[image]

However, the 3 missing orders are present in the database:

[image]

The strange thing to me is that the orders also appear in the "last 5 orders" widget on the dashboard, and I can open them by clicking on them there. So Magento seems to be loading the data correctly, just not loading it into the orders grid.

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: That would mean the `sales_flat_order_grid` is not updated with the correct data. But without any errors or direct indications on what it could be it's impossible to help you

Comment: You are right. The orders are present in `sales_flat_order` but missing in `sales_flat_order_grid`. It's plenty of help, at least I know where to start looking. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck! If you find any more details do post them if you need help

Comment: Hi i have the same problem, some orders are missing in the grid table because of an error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;" did you find a way to recreate the grid table?

Comment: @wutzebaer Unfortunately I don't think I can help. My issue was caused by an extension, so removing the extension solved the problem.

Comment: please check if there are errors in var/log/exception.log.

Comment: @wutzebaer you should increase the value for MYSQL "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" variable.

Comment: Increase "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" may help fix issue "General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded". But in fact, there is a sql that is slow in your code, maybe because of an extension. My suggestion is to enable mysql log and find out what is slow and fix it.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

That would mean the `sales_flat_order_grid` is not updated with the correct data. But without any errors or direct indications on what it could be it's impossible to help you